# I want to know how a ball can move in horizontal direction. I just made a ball while using this code please give some suitable answer

Tags: android

```
package com.example.circle;

import android.content.Context; 
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.OvalShape;
import android.view.View;

public class CircleView extends View{
int diameter;
int x;
int y;
private ShapeDrawable circle;
    public CircleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        createCircle();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    private void createCircle() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        x = 20;                 
        y = 20;
        diameter = 100;
        circle = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        circle.setBounds(x, y, x + diameter, y + diameter);
        circle.getPaint().setColor(0xff00cccc);
      }
      protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        circle.draw(canvas);

    }

}
```

this is the existing code which i am going through. please suggest me further that what should i do to make this ball move in horizontal direction using this code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like the following?

```
public void moveX(int amount) {
    x += amount;
    invalidate(); //repaint the screen
}
```

Then call the method upon a keypress or just a loop.